# The right answer to a topic is in a post that was deleted

Tags: discussion, moderation

[this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/34246/why-is-trunks-not-as-powerful-as-gohan-when-they-are-both-human-saiyan-hybrids) was about why Trunks didnt have the same power as Gohan when they are both saiyan-human hybrids. This was true in Dragon Ball Z, but now in Dragon Ball Super they made Trunks to be the first to get the super saiyan rage transformation, that by the time he gets it for the first time, it makes him able to fight Goku Black super saiyan rose, something that Goku and Vegeta couldnt do by that time (later with training and power from becoming angry and kaioken, Goku and Vegeta can also be a match to Goku Black super saiyan rose, or overpower him, but after Trunks did it for the first time)

The topic was first flagged because it was marked only "Dragon Ball Z" (so what could happen in Dragon Ball Super wouldnt count), and probably also because many people didnt like and couldnt accept at first the fact of how strong Trunks became so quickly, at first people was even having doubt if he had a new transformation, there was much noise about it for some weeks when these episodes appeared, one member who flagged said the answer "wasnt credible".

But later how powerful Trunks became was reaffirmed in the following episodes, even being the one who defeats merged Zamasu at the end. So the right answer is deleted, and I assume that if I post the same post again is going to get deleted again?

I ask you to reconsider undeleting the answer, so the topic can have a meaningful answer. Or post one yourself with the info I just posted here.

By the way, the answer isn't a one liner, it's 2 lines and there isn't much to add to the answer to explain it, perhaps that Trunks got a new transformation no one else got before, and that he showed to have hidden power as Gohan had

Comment: [this is a screenshot of the deleted answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2A5d.png) for those without the rep to see it

Comment: Two lines isn't much better than one line. I don't follow the series but I think you probably should add source like which chapter/episode were you referring to or add some pictures.

Comment: There is a difference between a claim and an answer. Your one line claim doesn't add much in way of an answer. Sure, it is now reaffirmed, but at that time, it is no more a claim. You may however now add supporting evidence (i.e, episode numbers, details and proofs) about when, where and HOW what you claim is actually right. And then **now** _that_ is an answer.

Comment: Yes, if you post the exact same post again, it will be deleted again, but if you post a longer, better explained post around the same idea, but with more details and citations, following the advice in кяαzєя's answer, it won't be deleted. As far as I know, Dragon Ball Z and Super are in the same continuity, so that's not a valid reason to delete an answer and I would vote to undelete if that were all, but the answer you posted is just way too short and doesn't even do basic diligence like mentioning an episode number or a scene that supports its claim.

Answer (score 5):

I disagree. You made no effort to explain why you are right. If you are going to give an answer you need to provide sufficient explanation. Use citations from canonical source material don't just make claims like XYZ character is now stronger than QVCR character because ABC series happened. Explain how they got more powerful, what they did to get more powerful and when it happened, with facts and citations. This makes your question stronger and more easily accepted by other users. Your answer being one or two lines makes no difference if you don't have anything to back up what you claim.

You may not have much to say, because you believe yourself to be an expert on the series, but know that not everyone maybe on your level of expertise and know what you are referencing. Answers that elaborate and explain things help others who aren't up to speed with things going on in the series. The answers here are a collaborative effort by the community to help everyone better understand various aspects of anime and manga, regardless of who asks the question.

Power levels and power struggles have always been a topic of ongoing debate. Sure theoretically even the weakest character can defeat the strongest, given the right circumstances. But there are a lot of factors at play that skew the balance in both canon and non-canon (e. g. Xenoverse) material. If you don't make an effort to back up your what you say, your claims hold as much weight with other people as someone claiming their car goes faster because it's red.